# searchable database based web application design

Tags: database, search-engine

I am new to web application development. I want to develop an java/mysql/tomcat web application. I want to make the application so that the data inside the database can be searchable by any search engine. How do I implement that?

Comment: I think you might have security issues letting just anybody interrogate your database. Or, do you have a way to identify search engines so you can distinguish them from some curious hacker? If you truly want to do this, look up "web services".

Answer (score 1):

Search engines don't read your database. They read the web pages. Make it so that all the information that you want searchable is accessible by following non-AJAX links from the outside. If you hide the information behind a login form, or even just a search form, the search engines won't be able to access the information.